# Unable to fetch some archives with apt-get?

Tags: apt

I try to use at-get update but it gives that error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 54,3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 201 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe traceroute amd64 1:2.0.15-1
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8008 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/traceroute/traceroute_2.0.15-1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8008 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I guess there is a network problem but cannot find the problem.

Do you have suggestion ?

Comment: Looks to me like it's trying to use a proxy - Check Synaptic > Preference > Network or does sudo cat /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf |grep useProxy run from a terminal give useProxy "1" which would imply it is.

Comment: no I dont use proxy also sudo cat /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf |grep useProxy gives '0'

Comment: Also it is idiotic that I can go to the URLs by browser and download packages however apt-get cannot

Comment: This has been happening alot since 12.04. I cannot be sure if it is a network issue or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. This is  because a program that is behaving like a proxy, also the silly fact is Ubuntu does not show the proxy settings correctly :).

I was using the webscabar (one of the pen test tool). For that program I set my proxy settings to capture request and response packets headers between the server and my browser. After I unistalled the program , settings are still remains. I just set all settings to system default from network settings.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some detail for others who might search for similar. Thanks.